# When should I perform transformation when analyzing skewed- data?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, multiple-regression, data-transformation

I am working on a project where I need to analyze the relationship between two variables (correlation, regression, anything that helps to understand what is the nature of the relationship).

From the following source I understood I should first calculate skewness and if the skewness value is over +- 0.5 I should take the square root of the data and if it is over -+ 1 I should take the log of the data:

http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1046/j.1365-2389.2001.00383.x/abstract

I don't understand if I am supposed to do that only when doing the regression analysis or before I start doing statistical tests.

Comment: There is no guarantee but you will typically find stronger relationships if you transform your data to reduce skew. So, I would use the transformed data throughout. Your rule of thumb for transformations may not be optimal.

Comment: Please be specific whether you are intending to apply regression or any other specific technique. A general question can not be replied in the present case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I am working on a project where I need to analyze the relationship between two variables (correlation, regression, anything that helps to understand what is the nature of the relationship).

"Understand the nature of the relationship" doesn't seem to require hypothesis tests or confidence intervals. This sounds more like exploratory data analysis  -- plots, summary statistics and the like, maybe looking at a regression to investigate what assumptions might be suitable.

If you are doing that you shouldn't use hypothesis tests on the same data - the tests will not have the desired properties any more (indeed there are a variety of consequences). If you need to do both a more suitable approach would be to pull off some of the data to do the investigations necessary to understand "the nature of the relationship" - such as formulate some model - and then do any testing on the remainder.]

> From the following source I understood I should first calculate skewness and if the skewness value is over ±0.5 I should take the square root of the data and if it is over ±1 I should take the log of the data

This correctly reports what is given in the paper but the advice is potentially mistaken on several grounds.

1. Firstly a minor point -- skewness itself doesn't necessarily relate well to the strength of the transformation that would be needed to achieve approximate normality.

   Consider, for example, the distribution for which the log-transformation will actually achieve normality.

   The lognormal distribution itself has skewness coefficient that varies from considerably less than $\frac12$ to considerably greater than $1$, so if we had a large sample - large enough to get an accurate estimate of the population skewness coefficient - from anything sufficiently close to a lognormal distribution, this advice would offer too weak a transformation when the skewness was below 1 (leaving it right skew). Here's an example -- moment-skewness values for three large samples from lognormal distributions with increasing $\sigma$ (shape) parameter and the skewness for square-root and log-transformed values:

   ```
                     x1     x2     x3 
    untransformed  0.436  0.837  1.220
    square root    0.221  0.413  0.600
    log transform  0.009  0.005  0.021
   ```

   You can see that taking the square root approximately halves the skewness when the distribution is lognormal -- irrespective of the actual skewness value (it's not hard to figure out why this halving should happen). The skewness-based rule would leave x1 alone, would take the square root of x2 and take the log of x3; x1 and x2 end up with skewness close to 0.5. The correct transformation here is to take logs every time.

   Now consider the gamma distribution; it's another commonly used distribution. Again, let's assume we have large enough samples to accurately estimate skewness. When its shape parameter is between 4 and 16 the skewness is between $\frac12$ and $1$, for which the advice suggests taking the square root transformation -- but this is too weak (though usually not terrible). Then when the shape parameter is below 4 (say at 2 or 3) it suggests taking logs, but this is much too strong, leaving it noticeably left-skew. A much more suitable transformation across all of those gamma distributions is the cube root. I also identified a distribution for which the square root is a suitable symmetrizing transformation (except at quite small values of one of its parameters); its population skewness varies from near 0 to above 1 (around then you get close to needing a stronger transformation than the square root ... but the log is still too strong). The point here is that a suitable transformation for those families is the same even as the skewness moves right across those skewness boundaries in the advice.

   Here's a second issue with using skewness to tell you how to transform. Imagine I have data from one of the distributions I named. If we shift it by a constant (equivalent to adding some value - like say 10 - to every number you get) then the skewness is unchanged - but a suitable symmetrizing transformation *has* changed:

   [image: histograms of x, log(x), x+10 and log(x+10) for standard lognormal X. x and x+10 are strongly right skew, log(x) is symmetric but log(x+10) is still pretty strongly right skew]

   Because transformations are sensitive to shifts but skewness is not, the skewness coefficient is (again) not well-related to the transformation choice.

   The advice in the paper there is perhaps a reasonable starting point for a symmetrizing transformation (indeed I applaud the focus there on effect-size concerns rather than on testing), but it's a bit over-simplified.

   This isn't the biggest issue though.
2. Symmetrical doesn't imply normal; there are perfectly symmetric distributions for which normal theory procedures will be unsuitable.
3. This is looking at the data before testing it, so it alters the property of any tests or confidence intervals (it won't have the significance level you chose, for example, and the power properties will be affected).
4. Once you transform, you are no longer fitting the same model you were; it's not always a simple matter to correctly translate the conclusions back to the original variables. (We do have plenty of posts on how to do that sort of thing here, so there's assistance to be had -- but it's not something so trivial that you can just ignore it.)

> I don't understand if I am supposed to do that only when calculating regression or basically before I start doing anything else, such as running correlation tests.

Here's the biggest issue:

If you're looking at the distribution of the dependent variable on its own, it doesn't make sense to do it like this for regression *at all*.

The normality assumption for regression (which only applies when you're using tests or intervals that assume normality) doesn't relate to the distribution of the response, $Y$. It relates to the distribution of the error term. The $Y$ values themselves may be very skewed in either direction without this necessarily being an issue - you simply can't tell from what they look like, and if you do transform them you may well be making matter worse. What you can do is examine the distribution of residuals (via a QQ plot say) but this is only of any use if the mean and variance of the residuals already behave as they should.

If you're looking at independent variables in regression there's no distributional assumption at all.

The more important consideration in regression is the shape of the relationship between the variables (the regression model assumes linearity; if you had it a transformation of one of the variables will change it to a nonlinear relationship), and to a lesser extent the suitability of the variance assumption (though that can be dealt with in other ways).

[As for whether you need it for correlation *it depends on what you're doing* with that correlation (are you just testing if it's 0? Are you building a confidence interval for it?), your assumptions about the variables and so on. If you don't have normality but you're doing something that requires it, there may be other alternatives. If you're interested in measuring linear relationships, moving directly to a rank correlation may not in general do what you seek.]

Comment: Thank you for your thorough answer. "Understand the nature of the relationship" wasn't the best way to put it - I am trying to answer my research question: "is there a statistically significant relationship between the level of rock fall danger and the amount and type of precipitation?"

As for the transformation, from what you say I understand it is a much complex procedure than I thought and I feel like it might be better not to do it at all rather than do it incorrectly.

Comment: No research question should contain the phrase "statistically significant relationship". That's a statistics question, translated from an actual research question (and maybe into something you shouldn't really care about very much). You should be getting statisticians to help you translate your actual research question to statistical questions -- we usually know what our language means and would often translate quite differently from what the overly-compressed guidebooks would suggest - and we're right here. ...ctd

Comment: ctd ... Transformation isn't *especially* complicated, but it's often presented wrongly (as it was in that paper), and often the best choice is to do something else. You can't ignore your regression assumptions; you should check them, but only the actual assumptions, not something else. We have many posts on site about regression assumptions.

Comment: An actual research question (a question a scientist would care about) might be "how are they related" or perhaps "are they related" (though I'd say it's obvious they can't be completely independent, so "are they related" is a pretty silly question to ask; they won't be completely unrelated). You might ask a policy oriented question like "are they related enough for it to be worth us to consider it in (say) road safety policy?") ... few of those real questions are answered well by hypothesis tests